# MatLab Parallel computing toolbox: using more cores for same task

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, spmd

I have a laptop with 4 *physical* cores, and the MatLab parallel computing toolbox. I need to perform two independent task (really expensive, let's say to compute the largest eigenvalue of a dense,large, matrix).

So, I want to distribute the tasks to my core in the following way:

- 2 cores on the first task
- 2 cores on the second task

but I really can't understand/find how to set this in a MatLab code.

After searching a lot, I've seen I should use `spmd`, but I can't find in the documentation a proper example that allows me to use **2  cores for the same task**.

Any  minimal working example in MatLab would be really appreciated!

**EDIT after Daniel's comment:**
After creating a parallel pool of 4, workers, I could do:

```
 spmd
     if labindex == 1 
        %first worker, do something             
     elseif labindex == 2
         %second worker, do sometihng
     end   
 end
```

**EDIT(2)**

I can set `NumThreads=2`, so each worker will do two tasks(right?). The question now is: do I have to create a parpool with **4** workers, so each worker does 2 threads? More explicitely:

`parpool(4);
%set NumThreads = 2 via Parallel computing toolbox
%define matrix A1, A2 of size 1000x1000
parfor i=1:2
    x(i) = max(abs(eigs(A(i))));
end`

I would like now that the first two cores work on the `x(1)`, while the other two on `x(2)`

---

**LAST EDIT**:

Using a `parfor` as written in the comments, I'd do:

```
c = parcluster('local');
A = {rand(2000), rand(2000),rand(2000), rand(2000),rand(2000), 
rand(2000),rand(2000),rand(2000)};
c.NumThreads = 2;
pool = parpool(c, 2); %2 workers
parfor i=1:8
   x(i) = max(abs(eig(A{i})));
end
```

Comment: What you are saying is quite advanced parallel code. Making *some* cores collaborate while others don't is non trivial. You will likely need targeted messaging and signal passing. Perhaps you can do this with an elaborate `parfor`.

Comment: @AnderBiguri afaik, this should be possible with `spmd` command. Do you have any idea about how to do that with a parfor? It would be great!

Comment: `spmd` is single program, multiple datasets. Its designed so each worker runs 1 same program but with a different inptut each. 2 workers collaborating will necesarily not have the same program, AFAIK. Maybe I am worng.

Comment: Ignoring the 2 cores in the first place, are you able to distribute your code on 2 workers using spmd?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I've edited my answer with what I can do

Comment: @Daniel that said, I can't understand how this could help. I'm probably missing something here...

Comment: Try setting the NumThreads property https://mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parallel.cluster.html Assuming the functions you are using can be run on multiple cores, matlab will use them.

Comment: @Daniel I just edited my post with your suggestion. Do you think I'm missing something?

Comment: Exactly what I would do. Then I would check in the task manager if it actually uses multiple cores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from the various comments, if you set a [cluster object's](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parallel.cluster.html) `NumThreads` property, then each worker you launch will use that number of computational threads. You can do this through the [Cluster Profile Manager](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/discover-clusters-and-use-cluster-profiles.html#btmmlnd), or programmatically.

When you launch `parpool`, the number you specify is the number of worker *processes* you want to launch, and each worker will have a number of threads corresponding to the cluster object's `NumThreads` property.

Putting this together, we get:

```
% Use the local cluster
c = parcluster('local');
% Make 2 'A' matrices
A = {rand(2000), rand(2000)};
for numThreads = 1:2
    % Set up cluster NumThreads property for this iteration
    c.NumThreads = numThreads;
    % Build a pool with 2 worker processes
    pool = parpool(c, 2);
    tic
    spmd
        % Each worker operates on a separate element of A
        out = max(abs(eig(A{labindex})));
    end
    t = toc();
    fprintf('Time with NumThreads = %d: %.3f\n', numThreads, t);
    delete(pool);
end
```

On my machine, the relevant timings are:

```
Time with NumThreads = 1: 4.693
Time with NumThreads = 2: 3.636
```

Comment: Thanks! I have two questions.

First of all, since I have 4 physical cores, and in your code you're using *2 workers*, then is it correct to say that each worker is "made by" 2 cores?

Comment: Also, I'm wondering how to do in the following scenario: let's say I have 8 matrices (and again 4 cores). Since `labindex` assume just two values, in the `spmd` I will compute just two of the spectral radius. In this case there is no way to achieve the task using `spmd`, so I should use a `parfor`, right?

Comment: Yes, when the cluster `NumThreads` is 2, then each worker process has 2 threads each. In the case where you have more matrices than cores, `parfor` is probably a better bet. (And you might well find that you're better off with `NumThreads` == 1 - worth testing)

Comment: Many thanks, I learned a lot. Just one last thing: I added an edit to my question regarding the computation with 8 matrices. I wrote the `parfor` loop, could you please confirm if that is right?

I mean, in this way I am using 2 cores to compute every spectral radius of every matrix, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right, 2 worker processes each with 2 computational threads.

Comment: It's almost everything clear. Just to be sure: with "thread" in this case you mean **the computation of a spectral radius**, right? So, for instance, at a generic iteration `i`, the first worker (made by 2 cores), uses these two threads to compute the spectral radius of a matrix.

Comment: Yes, in my example, the `eig` computation uses 2 threads behind the scenes. In MATLAB, this is called "implicit multithreading" - where a single MATLAB operation transparently uses multiple threads without you having to do anything in your code. https://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-multicore.html